# Is it possible to #include a namespaced class into another namespace

Tags: c++, c++11, namespaces, include

I am working through Bjarne Stroustrup's "The C Programming Language (4th edition)" and I came across an example in section 14.4.6 (Namespaces - Versioning) that I haven't been able to replicate. The example `#include`s a namespaced class declaration into another namespace. Here is my simplified attempt at reproducing this example:

// V3.h

```
namespace V3 {
    class C {
        public:
            void print();
    };
}
```

// V3.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "V3.h"

using namespace std;

namespace V3 {
    void C::print() {
        cout << "Hello from C" << endl;
    }
}
```

// Popular.h

```
namespace Popular {
    #include "V3.h"
}
```

// main.cpp

```
#include "Popular.h"

int main() {
    Popular::V3::C c;
    c.print();
}
```

When I attempt to compile this program I get the following output:

```
$ g++ main.cpp V3.cpp
/tmp/ccAVnUZi.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `Popular::V3::C::print()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Thus, I'm wondering, is it possible to `#include` a namespaced class into another namespace? Or am I failing to reproduce this example for other reasons? I read in a later section (15.2.5) that it may not be possible to do this.

Comment: You're including the header there but not the implementation. So `print()` is undefined.

Comment: Link V3.cpp also.

Comment: @CruzJean how do I include the implementation? I thought by adding V3.cpp as an argument to g++, I would be including it.

Comment: @J.R. Haven't I linked V3.cpp by writing `g++ main.cpp V3.cpp`?

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked that.

Comment: @johnnyodonnell The impl would need to be e.g. all in the header file. Then when you `#include` the header into namespace `Popular` it'll also have the impl in that (new) namespace as well. As it stands the class def is injected into `Popular` but the impl is only for the original namespace `V3`. Needs to be in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's totally possible (though highly questionable). `#include` is really nothing more than textual copy-paste. It's as-if your `Popular.h` was:

```
namespace Popular {
    namespace V3 {
        class C {
            public:
                void print();
        };
    }
}
```

This happens to be legitimate C++ code, there are certainly plenty of cases where it wouldn't be.

Note that this class `C` is `::Popular::V3::C`. That's a different, and unrelated, type from the one declared in `V3.h` - which is `::V3::C`. The second type has a definition for its `print()` function in `V3.cpp`.

But that's not the `print()` you're calling - you're calling `::Popular::V3::C::print()` (which is, again, a member function of a different type from `::V3::C`) and there's no definition for this function anywhere. So, as a result, you get an [undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12573816/2069064) - you need to add a definition for this thing. Like, say:

```
// Popular.cpp
#include <iostream>
void Popular::V3::C::print() {
    std::cout << "This is bad and I should feel bad about it. :-(" << std::endl;
}
```

But really, don't `#include` things inside of a `namespace` unless you have a really strongly compelling reason to do so. You could've instead provided a namespace alias:

```
#include "V3.h"
namespace Popular {
    namespace V3 = ::V3;
}
```

This would let you still write `Popular::V3::C`, which is now actually the same type as `::V3::C`.

Or a type alias:

```
#include "V3.h"
namespace Popular {
    using C = ::V3::C;
}
```

And here again `::Popular::C` is actually the same type as `::V3::C`.

Comment: This makes sense and I was able to get my example to work. I completely understand that this is not good practice, but wanted to see how it worked anyway. Thanks for the response!